# Raw vs Filtered in the output of cellranger count

Tags: scrnaseq, 10x-genomics

After running `cellranger count` I got two relevant for further analysis folders: `filtered_gene_bc_matrices` and `raw_gene_bc_matrices`. What is the difference between them? What does `cellranger` filter out, and what should we preferably use for further analysis?

Comment: Mostly people use the filtered gene bc matrix. Take a look at the guided tutorial for the r package Seurat if you're new to 10x and /or single cell (https://satijalab.org/seurat/pbmc3k_tutorial.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm unsure whether this is the answer you are looking for, but when looking into 10X cellranger documentation for the Matrices Output:

> **Unfiltered gene-barcode matrices**:
>   *Contains every barcode from fixed list of known-good barcode sequences. This includes background and non-cellular barcodes.*
>
> **Filtered gene-barcode matrices**:
>   *Contains only detected cellular barcodes.*

[Source](https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/output/matrices)